# how to disable phpmyadmin on a centos server?

Tags: centos

is there a way to disable phpMyAdmin from being accessed on my server while still keeping the install in case it is needed later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a file called `.htaccess` and place it in the directory with the phpMyAdmin installation with the following contents;

```
 deny from all
```

If you have a VirtualHost configured you will need to enable this like so;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.mydomain.com
....
<Directory /var/www/html>
AllowOverride All            
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

---

If you using the default apache httpd.conf i.e. your files are in `/var/www/html` then you need to change the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file like so, and `service httpd restart` change;

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
...
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None
```

to this;

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
...
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All             <------change this
```

---

As a further security suggestion. I would generally recommend restricting access to the phpMyAdmin installation folder during production and development usage, simply because phpMyAdmin is easy to leave open, and is popular with bots for automated exploitation by brute force etc. You can just allow your own IP (if you have a known static IP like so;)

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.123.123.123
```

Comment: I tried this and does not seem to work

Comment: ah, i was just adding a pointer about enabling the `Deny` rules in `httpd.conf` basically you need to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: I did this exactly using the "deny from all" but still no joy is this all that needs to be in the file?

Comment: If you have <VirtualHost *:80> configured, should should put `AllowOverride All` in there

Comment: ahh ok I put it in there but got a syntax error saying it wasn't allowed in there?

Comment: ahh,sorry different syntax in VirtualHost then. 2 mins. let me update

Comment: dont worry I got it had to add the 
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Comment: oops. my bad. In the VirtualHost, set it like this; `<Directory /var/www/html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>`